# Segmentation fault when trying to print out a struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to make a code that will allow the user to input any amount of entries he wants, and then print them out (and other functions, still have to get to that). But when I try to launch the code it allows me to input the entries, but when I want to print them out, it doesn't register `current.name` or `current.telNo` (only prints out `1:  has tel. No.` ) and a segmentation error follows after it. Any idea how I can fix that.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int listSize;
int counter = 0;

struct Entry {
        char name[20];
        char telNo[9];
        struct Entry *next;
} current;

int main()
{
    struct Entry *linkedList = (struct Entry * )malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    struct Entry *current = linkedList;
    first(current);
    print(current);
    return 0;
}

void first(struct Entry linkedList)
{
    int i;
    printf("enter list size: ");
    scanf("%d", &listSize);
    printf("Now enter entries one by one: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        counter++;
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", linkedList.name);
        printf("Telephone: ");
        scanf("%s", linkedList.telNo);

        if (i != listSize -1) {
            linkedList.next = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
            linkedList = *linkedList.next;
        } else {
            linkedList.next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void print(struct Entry linkedList)
{
    int nr = 1;
    printf("\nTelephone book is:\n");
    while (current.name != NULL) {
        printf("%d: %s has tel. No.\t%s\n", nr, current.name, current.telNo);
        current = *current.next;
        nr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `current = *current.next` is undefined behavior when `current.next == NULL`

Comment: `first()` is modifying a copy of `current`.

Comment: Okay and how can i change so it modifes current not the copy ? Do i make it as a pointer ?

Comment: You should pass pointers to structures, not pass the structure by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of . you should have used **->** and in your **print()** you were traversing **current** instead of **linkedList** which was causing the issue. Also your functions definitions should come before its usage. Please check the below snippet, i have made the corresponding changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int listSize;
int counter = 0;

struct Entry {
    char name[20];
    char telNo[9];
    struct Entry *next;
} current;


void print(struct Entry *linkedList)
{
    int nr = 1;
    printf("\nTelephone book is:\n");
    while (linkedList->name != NULL) {
      printf("%d: %s has tel. No.\t%s\n", nr, linkedList->name, linkedList->telNo);
      linkedList = linkedList->next;
      nr++;
    }

} 
void first(struct Entry *linkedList)
{
    int i;
    printf("enter list size: ");
    scanf("%d", &listSize);
    printf("Now enter entries one by one: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        counter++;
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", linkedList->name);
        printf("Telephone: ");
        scanf("%s", linkedList->telNo);

        if (i != listSize -1) {
            linkedList->next = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
            linkedList = linkedList->next;
        } else {
            linkedList->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Entry *linkedList = (struct Entry * )malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    struct Entry *current = linkedList;
    first(current);
    print(current);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (current.name != NULL)
```

should be

```
while (current != NULL)
```

otherwise `current = *current.next` will become `NULL` and crash on the while condition

Comment: that doesnt work :(  it pops out a diferent error  ```error: invalid operands to binary != (have 'struct Entry' and 'void *')
         while (current != NULL)```

Comment: because current is not a pointer but a struct. Change its type to a pointer to that struct in the print method and also first method (otherwise you will modify a copy of current and not current)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your code but, essentially two main 'points of confusion':

First, you seem to be confusing a structure (`struct Entry`) with a pointer-to-structure (as in, for example, `struct Entry *next;`).

Second, you have two different variables called `current` - one defined ***globally*** (which is the *only* one that is 'visible' to your `print` function), and another one defined ***locally*** inside `main` (this one will 'hide' the former).

Here is a corrected version of your code, with triple-slash (///) comments wherever I've made changes. Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int listSize;
int counter = 0;

struct Entry {
    char name[20];
    char telNo[9];
    struct Entry* next;
} *current; /// Here, we define a GLOBAL variable, "current" that is a POINTER to the struct

void first(struct Entry* linkedList); /// Put "Function Prototypes* here, so that "main" knows what they are
void print(struct Entry* linkedList); /// You need to pass POINTERS to structures, not the actual structures

int main()
{
    struct Entry* linkedList = (struct Entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
//  struct Entry* current = linkedList; /// This declaration 'hides' the global variable
    current = linkedList; /// Here, we (properly) assign the global pointer's value

    first(current);
    print(current);
    return 0;
}

void first(struct Entry* linkedList) /// Pointer (see above)
{
    int i;
    printf("enter list size: ");
    scanf("%d", &listSize);

    printf("Now enter entries one by one: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        counter++;
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", linkedList->name); /// Use "->" instead of "." to get a pointer's member (and elsewhere)
        printf("Telephone: ");
        scanf("%s", linkedList->telNo); /// See above

        if (i != listSize - 1) {
            linkedList->next = (struct Entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry)); /// See above
            linkedList = linkedList->next; /// Again - changed here to use pointers!
        }
        else {
            linkedList->next = NULL; /// See above
        }
    }
}

void print(struct Entry* linkedList)  /// Pointer (see above)
{
    int nr = 1;
    printf("\nTelephone book is:\n");
    while (current != NULL) { /// You need to check if "current" is not NULL before trying to access any of its members...
//  while (current.name != NULL) {
        printf("%d: %s has tel. No.\t%s\n", nr, current->name, current->telNo); /// Same "." to "->" changes as before
        current = current->next; /// And again!
        nr++;
    }
}
```

*There are other ways to 'fix' your code (and also improve it): for example, you never use the argument you pass to `print`, relying instead on the 'global' variable I mentioned earlier.*

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I kinda got all of it if i have further problems when i will add the delete funcion or sorting funcion then i will ask again.

Answer (score 0):

`current.name` is a pointer to reserved 20-byte area, which is always non-NULL.
I would initialize *next with NULL every time I allocate it (there are few ways to do that, easiest: assign NULL to it right after malloc). And do the check like that: `if (current.next != NULL)`.
You also can check for `current.name[0] != 0`, but the first option is cleaner.